# Adding time field to the current date field using Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

**Problem:** I'm making some sort of to-do application in Laravel, so for each to-do a user creates there will be a given time from the user to indicate when this to-do has to be completed. Now I have 2 input fields, 1 for the date and 1 for the specific time. I want to add the time input to the date input and when that is completed I want it to store in the database

**Question:** How do I add my time field value to my date value?

**Code:**

**The input fields:**

```
{{Form::date('date', \Carbon\Carbon::today(),['class' => 'form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0'])}}
{{Form::time('time', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->timezone('Europe/Brussels')->format('H:i'),['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

**My store function when the user wants to add a task:**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {

    $this ->validate($request, ['title' => 'required|max:25','description' => 'required|max:60']);

    $task = new Task;
    $task -> title = $request->input('title');
    $task -> description = $request->input('description');
    $task -> end_date = $request->input('date');
    $task -> user_id = auth()->id();
    $task->save();

    return redirect('/tasks')->with('success', 'Task created');
 }
```

**My Task.php model where I try to manipulate the 'end_date' attribute:**

```
    public function setEndDateAttribute($date) 
    {

    $this->attributes['end_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);

    }
```

The result I'm getting: Date is being added to the database, but with above function I get the date + current time of creating the task. I want to replace current time with my input value of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change format,

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
```

Will get only the year, month and day of your input, but you need also hours, minutes (and maybe seconds). So you have to change your code like that:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
```

Anyway, i think it's easier for you if you set the `$dates` attribute in your model, have a look at the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#soft-deleting):

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

If you add your column to this array will be automatically returned a `Carbon\Carbon` object.

#### Update:

In your form you have 2 inputs: `date` and `time`, so you have 2 options:

- Like I was saying in the comment, do not use a form builder
- Merge these 2 inputs in a single Carbon object...

So your code has to be changed from:

```
$task -> end_date = $request->input('date');
```

to:

```
$task -> end_date = $request->input('date') . ' ' . $request->input('time');
```

And your mutator has to be changed as described above.

Comment: Is it possible for you to show me how I can add my time in to the end_date attribute? `createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);` this isn't adding my time I want, my time is a different input field so I need somehow to add it in

Comment: Well in my opinion, first of all you shouldn't use a form builder... use raw HTML with a [datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and, and blade features like [Componets & slots](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#components-and-slots)

Anwyway I'll update my answer!

Comment: As far as I understand the idea is to work with Carbon Instance, and no to store raw  "date / time" input in the database, so this does not answer the question.

Comment: @Kyobul attributes in `$dates` array are automatically mutated to [`DateTime` / `Carbon instances`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L89) objects...

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
 protected $dates = ['end_date'];


 // Check if a valide DateTime can be created

 if ((bool)\DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i',  $request->input('date') . ' '. $request->input('time') )) {

 // Store it in database     

 $task -> end_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $request->input('date') . ' '. $request->input('time'))->toDateTimeString();

 }
```